# destructing api response in vuejs 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, destructuring, vue-composition-api

how do I destructure the response to access results?

the code is

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const result = ref(null)

    onMounted(async ()  => {
      result.value = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api?results=50')
      const { result: {data: {results} } } = results.value
    })
    return { result }
  }
}
```

the response returned looks like
[image]

the console error is "Cannot access 'results' before initialization"

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [response](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/3958e9f/README.md#response-schema) returned from `axios.get()` stores the data in its `data` property, so `result.value.data` contains the `info` and `results` fields.

However, I think you're trying to store the `results` field in the `result.value` ref. You could store the API response in a temporary variable, and then destructure that:

```js
onMounted(async ()  => {
  const resp = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api?results=50')
  const { data: { results } } = resp
  result.value = results
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-destructure-axios-response?file=src/App.vue)